# Installation of Pyobject in windows 10 Anaconda environment.

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I am trying to use gstreamer with my Anaconda environment on Windows 10 machine. I get gstreamer successfully installed on my machine. The version of Gstreamer is 1.13, the latest for windows. But now I want to use it through Python IDE. But as my machine does not have installed Pyobject ,it throws error like no module named gi.I have used pip install, downloaded the zip file and then run python setup.py install and also through conda install command, but nothing works. How can I install pyobject and pygst on Anaconda environment ?